# How does ground affect a battery? (Nodal Analysis)

Tags: voltage, ground

I began solving this question with nodal analysis, but I ran into 2 problems while solving the question:

1. V_A has to be equal to zero to solve the question (and get R_1). I get 40V... I think that ground is affecting my battery?... Why is this?
2. I got a negative value for R_3. Does this mean the current is in the wrong direction that I assumed?

[image: Question1]

Comment: It looks like you've labeled the polarity of the battery the wrong way around. The long bar of the battery symbol is positive. The short bar is negative.

Comment: According to your diagram, the line with the earth symbol is reference 0V. \$V_A\$ is not zero.

Comment: The long line in the battery symbol is normally the positive terminal - which matches the +10V and -10V labels at the right side of the drawing.  "Ground" is, by definition, Zero Volts, and the point we use as a reference when measuring voltages elsewhere in the circuit.